# Why is it becomes oval?

Tags: modifiers

Do you have any idea why is it oval?

[image]

I need it to be like this

[image]

Comment: hello, you don't give enough informations, please describe your problem in details, thanks.

Comment: it is very unclear what you are trying to say ... did you add a primitive into the scene and it turned into that? did you add some kind of modifier to the object? If you don't know, can you include a link to your .blend in the post?

Comment: https://we.tl/t-u15T3uoy1Y

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded your file and I found 2 modifiers on the cylinder. For this you did not really need modifiers. If you still want to use a Subdivision Surface modifier then, in this case, you would use the Simple mode instead of the Catmull-Clark one. Not really sure what you wanted to achieve with the Displace modifier.
It was easier to start with a new cylinder.

I deleted your old cylinder and did the following:

1. Added another cylinder
2. Rotated it 90 degrees on the Y axis.
3. Scaled it on the Y axis so looks a bit like the one on your image.
4. Entered into Edit Mode and selected Face select mode.

[image]

5. Selected one end of the cylinder and tapped the Delete keyboard and from popup menu selected Faces
6. Selected the other end and did the same delete sequence.
7. Re-positioned the open ended cylinder to roughly match your image.
8. Switched back to Object Mode
9. At the Tools menu clicked on the Smooth under the Shading, see below

[image]

End result below.

[image]